# Multiple linear layout with Scroll view?

Tags: android, xml, layout

What I'm trying to achieve is this:

[image]

But what I have is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:layout_width="290dp"
    android:layout_height="490dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:background="#2a873e"
    tools:context="com.sumo.traffic.PlacesFilters"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.6"
            android:text="Button" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.6"
            android:text="Button" />

    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

When applying scroll view it shows that the scroll view can only host one single layout.
Would there be another possible way to produce what I want to achieve?

I'm putting more than 10 buttons in a single activity that's why i need a scrollview in my layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" >
  <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="0px"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.4"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="0px"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.6"
                android:text="Button" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="0px"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.4"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_width="0px"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.6"
                android:text="Button" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView></LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="width"
        android:layout_height="height"
    android:background="#2a873e"
        tools:context="com.sumo.traffic.PlacesFilters"
    android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"/>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="0px"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.4"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="0px"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.6"
                android:text="Button" />

        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="0px"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.4"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_width="0px"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.6"
                android:text="Button" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <ScrollView>
```